# How to make input required

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is that when both fields i.e. `fname` and `lname` are kept empty, the pop-up window should show both messages i.e. "First name must be filled out", "Last name must be filled out".

What modifications do I need to do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                document.myForm.fname.focus();
                return false;
            }

            var y = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
            if (y == null || y == "") {
                alert("Last name must be filled out");
                document.myForm.lname.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">First name:
    <input type="text" name="fname">Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Please search for "validating if input empty", there are hundreds of results.

Comment: If you are using Firefox in Chrome it's really helpful to open up the console. The console should tell you what errors occur so you know what you have to fix. You can also type javascript directly into the console to test things without making a whole new file.

Comment: remember, it is never *really* required on the client-side. Be sure to validate just as much (if not more so) on the server-side.

Comment: Another option would be to use jQuery along with the validation plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will give you some ideas about how to proceed:

```
function validateForm() {
    var errors = [],
        fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"],
        lname = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"];

    if (lname.value == "") {
        errors.unshift("Last name must be filled out");
        lname.focus();
    }
    if (fname.value == "") {
        errors.unshift("First name must be filled out");
        fname.focus();
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert("Cannot submit\n" + errors.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MKdg5/

The first thing you'll notice is that it is easier to read because blocks are indented. Also:

- You currently use `document.forms["myForm"]["fname"]` and `document.myForm.fname` to access the same field. Pick one way and use it consistently, or
- Create a variable that references the field, `fname`, and then use `fname.value` and `fname.focus()`
- Don't bother testing for `null` because the `.value` property never will be.
- Instead of immediately alerting an error and returning, add the error text to an array and then at the end test if the array is empty.

Comment: Clear and understandable for a beginner! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate your field as:

```
if (!x || x.length == 0)
```

Comment: Given that in the OP's code `x` is a string, why would you test `!x` as well as `x.length`? Also, the question is asking how to change the code to display a single error message about both fields.

Comment: Read it again - not single error, but both. !x means not null and  not undefined etc. Length > 0 means x is not empty.

Comment: Sorry, length == 0 means empty.

Comment: x is a _string_  (because that's what the _.value_ property returns) and so will not ever be null or undefined. _!x_ will be _true_ if x is an empty string, so the length check is redundant. And (again) the OP wants to combine the x and y validations such that they produce a single message.

Comment: You won, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Hthml 5 `required`. It's so much simpler and neat.

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" required="required">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" required="required">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/93CFN/)

**Note:** The `required` attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome. But it is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Comment: That is a nice neat way to go, but it [doesn't work with my browser](http://caniuse.com/form-validation). (Although given that the OP needs to have server-side validation too perhaps it isn't critical if the client-side validation doesn't work for old IE.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Well i was about to update my answer..:)..I know it's limited but it's high time we should start using html5 attributes though i agree with your point that it's not compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

BAsed on your validateForm function, your code would never check the second field. When using the return statement, the function will stop executing, and return the specified value.
A solution is use nested if statements and check both fields in one conditional block

```
if (x==null || x=="")
{
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
    //codes for both are not validated
    }
    else
    {
    //codes for just x is not validated
    }
}
else
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
    //codes for y is not validated
    }
    else
    {
    //codes for all validated
    }
```

This way use of return statement in each block won't break your function execution